# For-loop stops instead of skipping a row

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I would like to copy a range of cells in a row to another sheet.

Sometimes a row should be skipped because a cell in that row is blank.

My code stops at the row with the blank cell rather than continuing to the next.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Sheet1 'sheet in the input workbook
Set pasteSheet = Book1.Sheet2 'sheet in the output workbook

If ToggleButton.Value = True Then

   For j = 79 To 113

       If Trim(copySheet.Cells(j, 4).Value2) = vbNullString Then Exit For

       copySheet.Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j, 8)).Copy
       pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

   Next

End If

ToggleButton.Value = False

 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exiting the loop in case of an empty row, which is what you don't want. You want to continue but not do the copy in case of an empty row.
This should work :

```
  If Trim(copySheet.Cells(j, 4).Value2) <> vbNullString Then  

         copySheet.Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j, 8)).Copy
         pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    end if
```